# Custom monitoring circuit for a power supply

Tags: power-supply

I need to replace the failed power supply for an alarm system, I managed to find a replacement for the power supply but I'm having some problem understanding a circuit my late father jury-rigged to it. My electronics knowledge is quite low, I only know the bits I picked up from him.

The alarm system requires a 12V 5A input with the canonical positive and negative inputs, but requires also a third monitoring (anti-tampering?) input, which is the part my father hacked on.

Below is the schematic of the circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7NnTF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

`D1` is a WeEn Semiconductors BYW29EX-200 rectifier ([Mouser product page](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/WeEn-Semiconductors/BYW29EX-200127?qs=me8TqzrmIYV7T624nmp3Dw%3D%3D), [datasheet](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/848/BYW29EX-200-1846773.pdf)).

From my understanding the `?` pin is receiving a trickle current from `R1` (0.012A 0.144W) whenever the power supply is on (which should be always).

`R2` should be a pull-down to prevent `?` from floating when the power fails.

What I'm not understanding is the reason for the rectifier: since the power is already DC what's its role?

I have the technical documents and schematics of the alarm system but they don't explain anything on how the pins work because they're treated as a black-box and the supplier won't provide help as they want to provide their 2500% mark-up power supply.

Comment: Well, we don't know what the mystery system is expecting so we don't know what the resistors or diodes do here. Better post the schematics since you have them.

Comment: If the annotation on U1 is correct, then I will guess that the "?" pin is "ground", and that the R1-R2 voltage divider is meant to give us half the supply voltage (6V). Then  U1 can think that it is getting -6V and +6V. Just a guess.  Since the diode has a _low forward voltage drop_ and _guaranteed reverse surge and ESD capability_ perhaps it is just there for reverse polarity protection (i.e. connecting the battery backwards). Good luck!

Comment: @Justme the schematics do not explain any details regarding the wiring or the components, they only list "this is the PSU, connect it there".

Comment: @aMike I do know that the component expects +12V DC on `+V` and +0V DC on `-V`. I'm mainly puzzled by the rectifier: this is a static wiring, once you connect the PSU to the PCB you'll never touch any wiring again; there's a battery but it's connected through a completely different wiring to another part of the PCB.

Comment: @Justme if you''re curious the only schematics that's available is this: https://staticpro.comelitgroup.com/storage/2022/03/30963/ai-022-generale.pdf The PSU is in the top left, "PSU15". There's a technical manual but it's available only in Italian and doesn't mention any wiring, only general values and nothing about the pins.

Comment: It is puzzling. The diode might still be for protection against connecting the battery backwards.  That *?* line looks like its the *A* line throughout the schematic. With its twin the *B* line, they are sent with V+ and V- to all the modules. Maybe they are lines that get pulled low or high to signal an event? Then the two resistors serve to bias the line to a neutral state mid-way between +12 and ground? All conjecture on my part... sorry.